# How can I resize an iFrame from within the child page?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Is there a way of resizing an iFrame when the content within changes dimensions, for example
after a javascript effect?

In my example link I have used a Show/Hide Javascript Effect, but the resulting overflow is getting hidden because my iframe can't communicate.

[My Website Example](http://www.taskmotivator.com/Iframe_test.html) (Click Page 2 and you'll see the longer text is hidden)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible. It's done by Facebook app for example.

To access the iframe from the main document:

```
window.frames['iframeName'].document.callAFunction()
window.frames['iframeName'].document.getElementById('foo')
```

From iframe to parent document:

```
parent.document.callAFunction()
parent.document.getElementById('foo')
```

Keep in mind that this only works, if both documents loaded from the same domain.

Now you can do:

- Fetch an event if the iframe content changes
- Submit the new size into the parent document
- The parent document changes the iframes dimension

Comment: We'll tried several combinations, still it's just not expanding my Parent page when I click to open that <a href="javascript:showonlyone('Orders');" >Page 2</a> Div.

Here's my page again: http://www.taskmotivator.com/ParentPage.html

Maybe i'm missing which Id's to replace Foo with?

Comment: You need to write you functions for resizing on your own. I just showed you how to communicate between iframe and the parent document. I believe with thin hints and some googleing arround you should be able so solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Enclose the iFrame in a div, assign width and height of iFrame to 100% and control the height/width of the div.